# AngularJS ng-repeat ng-selected select box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<select class="input--select" ng-model="updatemember.client_company_id" ng-change="updatestreet()">
    <option ng-repeat="company in companies" ng-value="company.id" ng-selected="{{company.id == updatemember.client_company_id}}">{{ company.name }}</option>
</select>
```

I have the above that I'm using to repeat a json list and also choose a value if it matches up. This all work but when I click on the select box there is a blank value that looks like this:

`<option value="? string:2 ?"></option>`

Is there any way to get rid of this or have I done the `ng-repeat` all wrong?

Comment: Check the json first: try something like console.log(companies)

Comment: @collimarco it outputs three objects as expected, but the DOM renders 4 which is a blank option

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using `ng-options`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you are doing you can use `ng-options`.

```
<select class="input--select" 
    ng-model="updatemember.client_company_id" ng-change="updatestreet()"
    ng-options="company.id as company.name for company in companies">
</select>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/67p5f2xz/)**